# String to date PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, date

I've searched many questions, but every solution I tried, failed.

Basically, I get a string, for example: "1994-10-29"
I have a Date field inside my SQL database. I want to convert this to a Date but when I do, I always get 1970-01-01 which indicates the conversion failed.

My code:

```
    $date = $_GET["age"];
    $dob = strtotime($date);
    $date_of_birth = date('Y-m-d', $dob);
```

This is where it goes wrong. I've echo'd the $date and I get the right string from it. The INSERT statement after it also works, since I've tried it with a handpicked date.

I also read a solution where they user str_replace, tried replacing the '-' in my string with '/' but still didn't work.

Hope someone can help me out!

Comment: What is the value of $_GET["age"] ?

Comment: the string I gave as an example.

Comment: if your column has a DATE type, then you can insert your $_GET["age"] without any modification

Comment: No because that's what I originally had, $_get["age"] is in string format, when i insert it, it just inserts 0000-00-00

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
     $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
     echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Reference: 
http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php

I hope this is what you are looking for :)

Comment: Nop, this also gives me 1970-01-01

Comment: It worked, made a mistake! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `$_GET['age']` variable does not have a valid date string.  Here is the specification for `strtotime()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Here are the valid formats:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Ensure the string inside `$_GET['age']` is in the correct format.

When you insert into SQL, it's probably in "Y-m-d H:i:s" format, ensure what you are inserting is in this format.

Echo the variable you are inserting.  Is it the actual `$date` variable?  If so!  Then you want to reformat that `$date` variable!

Comment: But in my database the field has Date as type, not Datetime, since it's for your date of birth. So I don't think i need time as well as date?

Comment: @Djorren - ah ok, well whatever format, make sure it's in the correct format going into your database and that the string being translated by `strtotime` is correct by datetime.formats link I gave you.  It's most likely a date conversion issue you are having.  Are you sure that the data in `$_GET['age']` is ALWAYS in the same format coming in?  Check for these things.